# Weird Icon of Photos APP Being Displayed in Recycler View?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a Recycler View with GridLayoutManager for displaying a set of data stored on Disk. But when I update the first element it randomly shows an icon of my Image with the photos app Icon at the bottom and when I click it, it opens that Image in Photos app. What is happening here?
[image]

you can see the icon right there.
Here is my code :

Adapter

```
public class AdapterForCardView extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterForCardView.CardAdapterHolder>
{
private Context context;
private File[] image_files;
private File[] strings_of_files;
private String logging=getClass().getSimpleName();
public AdapterForCardView(Context context, File[] image_files, File[] strings_of_files)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.image_files = image_files;
    this.strings_of_files = strings_of_files;
}

@Override
public CardAdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.card_view_recycler,parent,false);
    return new CardAdapterHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(CardAdapterHolder holder, int position)
{
    Glide.with(context).load(image_files[position]).into(holder.getImageView());
    if (position!=holder.Position())
    {
        if (holder.Position()!=-1)holder.getLoadingText().cancel(true);
        removeAllText(holder.getTableLayout());
        LoadingText loadingText = new LoadingText(context,holder.getTableLayout());
        holder.setLoadingText(loadingText, position);
        loadingText.execute(strings_of_files[position]);
    }
}

private void removeAllText(TableLayout tableLayout)
{
    tableLayout.removeAllViews();
}

public void setStrings_of_files(File[] strings_of_files)
{
    this.strings_of_files = strings_of_files;
}

public void setImage_files(File[] image_files)
{
    this.image_files = image_files;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return image_files==null?0:image_files.length;
}

class CardAdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    private TableLayout tableLayout;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private LoadingText loadingText;
    private int position;
    public CardAdapterHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        imageView=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_card_view);
        tableLayout=(TableLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
        position=-1;
    }

    public ImageView getImageView()
    {
        return imageView;
    }

    public TableLayout getTableLayout()
    {
        return tableLayout;
    }

    public LoadingText getLoadingText()
    {
        return loadingText;
    }

    public void setLoadingText(LoadingText loadingText,int position)
    {
        this.loadingText = loadingText;
        this.position=position;
    }

    public int Position()
    {
        return position;
    }
}
}
```

Layout :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView android:id="@+id/card_view"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="250dp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
                                    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view_card_view"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="170dp"
                   android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="80dp"
                     android:layout_below="@id/image_view_card_view"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is code on how I update my data and notify the first item being changed

```
public class AsyncTaskForInternalFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, File[]>
{
private Context context;
private AdapterForCardView adapterForCardView;
private File[] labels;
private boolean ifSaved;
private String logging=getClass().getSimpleName();
public AsyncTaskForInternalFiles(Context context, AdapterForCardView adapterForCardView,boolean ifSaved)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.adapterForCardView=adapterForCardView;
    this.ifSaved=ifSaved;
}
@Override
protected File[] doInBackground(Void... params)
{
    File internal_save = context.getDir(context.getResources().getString(R.string.directory_images), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File[] files = internal_save.listFiles();
    labels=context.getDir(context.getResources().getString(R.string.directory_labels),Context.MODE_PRIVATE).listFiles();
    sortItOut(files,labels);
    return files;
}

private void sortItOut(File[] files, File[] labels)
{
    PairForSorting[] pairForSorting=new PairForSorting[files.length];
    PairForSorting[] labelsForSorting=new PairForSorting[files.length];
    for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
        pairForSorting[i] =new PairForSorting(files[i]);
        labelsForSorting[i]=new PairForSorting(labels[i]);
        Log.d(logging,files[i].getAbsolutePath()+"=fileNames");
        Log.d(logging,labels[i].getAbsolutePath()+"=labelNames");
    }
    Arrays.sort(pairForSorting);
    Arrays.sort(labelsForSorting);
    for (int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
    {
        files[i]=pairForSorting[i].fi;
        labels[i]=labelsForSorting[i].fi;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(File[] files)
{
    if (files != null)
    {
        adapterForCardView.setImage_files(files);
        adapterForCardView.setStrings_of_files(labels);
        if (ifSaved)adapterForCardView.notifyItemInserted(0);
        else adapterForCardView.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
}
```

If you need any more code feel free to comment.

If you want a recording I can send that too.

Comment: PS: Sorry for the weird photos.

Comment: Are you testing this on a custom ROM?

Comment: Well it's on oxygen OS coz I have one plus two.

Comment: I would guess it's some inbuilt functionality of that. Can you test on something else; an emulator, possibly?

Comment: Well in an hour I'm gonna pick up other devices to run on it. I'll then check it up. Motorola has a pure Android ROM so there it should show clearly.

Comment: Bdw is it possible the media scanner is doing that. Coz after I save my image I'm using media scanner to scan it and include in the gallery.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say it's possible it's because of that. You could try not performing the scan to find out.

Comment: well seems like it was the broadcast to mediaScanner creating the problem. Since it was being done from another activity returning to the main one I changed it and then at the update part of the recycler view added it. Doesn't seem to come now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the MediaScanner was creating the problem when broadcasting to add the picture to the Gallery. 
Don't know still if the problem was coz I was using Oxygen OS or if it creates the same bug in all Android phones.
Since it was happening at the transition back from another Activity just added the MediaScanner in the MainActivity to which it was returning and now it doesn't show again. Will update if this was only in Oxygen OS or was a problem in normal Androids also once I test it on them.